# Catching net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED for fixing bad img links

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a blog going for over 10 years & I would like to run a piece of Javascript on it that catches broken links. I was using:

```
function trackError(e) {
    var ie = window.event || {};
    var errMsg = e.message || ie.errorMessage || "404 error on " + window.location;
    var errSrc = (e.filename || ie.errorUrl) + ': ' + (e.lineno || ie.errorLine);
    mailme([errMsg, errSrc]);
}

// Triggering an error in the console:
// You have to use something like setTimeout(function() { notThere(); }, 0);
window.addEventListener('error', trackError, true);
```

But that's not catching the error in a useful way. What was broken, on which line etc.

[image: Error loading an image]

`JSON.stringify` of the error object results just in `"{"isTrusted":true}"` which is useless. I noticed in Chrome there is `e.path`, but not in Firefox. Is there a way in Javascript to log useful information about broken image links or I need to file bugs on browser engines?

Comment: When/where are you attempting to retrieve the information within the broken links? For example, are they `<img>` tags, or are you doing some ajax?

Comment: img tag https://natalian.org/2004/09/29/london/

Answer (score 9):

It's working. It will not stop the error from showing in Chrome in your console but it's working. Don't be bothered by the fact that you still SEE the error in Chrome. Your code is executing and you can write your `mailme` function and it will execute. I used the following to test:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://pictures.natalian.org/screenies/2004/sep/29/13:23:00/">
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var mailme = function() {
    console.log('Caught!');
}

window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    var ie = window.event || {};
    var errMsg = e.message || ie.errorMessage || "404 error on " + window.location;
    var errSrc = (e.filename || ie.errorUrl) + ': ' + (e.lineno || ie.errorLine);
    mailme([errMsg, errSrc]);
}, true);
```

**output (Chrome)**

[image]
**output (Firefox)**

[image]

Comment: Crucially it's not displaying anything about the error in either browser. That's really the issue I think.

Comment: Actually, I tested it in Chrome (by `console.log(arguments)`) and the error event contains not only the error code, but also the path to the element that caused the error and the URL that caused it.

Comment: Is it possible that the initial request for the content is refused from the server due to lack of access before the initial handshake? You could try adding location tags to your web.config to allow all users to a given directory such as ~/Content/images.

Comment: in 2016/1 December  again re-tested. But its not working i do not get the caught. in Google chrome stable

Answer (score 6):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror:

> When a resource (such as an `<img>` or `<script>`) fails to load, an error event using interface Event is fired **at the element**, that initiated the load, and the onerror() handler **on the element** is invoked. These error events **do not bubble up to window**, but (at least in Firefox) can be handled with a single capturing window.addEventListener.

(Highlighting by me.)

So it might simply be an issue of what it says there for Firefox, is not the same for Chrome.

Comment: It sounds to me as if Firefox has implemented it this way, even if it contradicts the specification (if those events do not bubble up per specification, then you should not be able to catch them on window.)

Comment: The `true` parameter being passed to `addEventListener` overrides event propagation. It basically means "don't allow anything below me to catch this event." See: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @RichardPressler: _“It basically means "don't allow anything below me to catch this event””_ – but does that also make an event that is explicitly specified as _not_ bubbling up, bubble up all of a sudden?

Comment: Kind of. Bubble and capture are the two event propagation modes. By setting `useCapture` to true, we are effectively disabling bubbling for this event being fired from child elements and setting the `window` object as the handler for this event type explicitly.

Comment: @Richard Thanks, I am aware of bubbling and capturing in general, but I wasn’t aware that an event that doesn’t bubble can still be captured. (But when you think about it, it makes sense of course.)

Comment: Honestly, as with anything, it could randomly stop working tomorrow if the browser vendors wish it. I've noticed the documentation around this type of thing remains vague, and tends to change without notice.

Comment: I've noticed there are no details of the error on the error object. So I would be mailing myself with no details of the error on the page, right?

Comment: Well you at least have access to the info what URL the error occurred on, via the `location` object. According to the linked MDN page, when using `window.onerror`, you would get the following parameters passed to your handler: message, source, lineno, colno, error. Whether or not those contain any useful information when catching image load errors, I haven’t checked.

Comment: Plus, after the page is done loading, you could go through all images on it, and see if they have a width/height – those that didn’t load, should have either 0 or undefined. That would at least help narrow down the list of “candidates” if there’s a lot of images on the page, so that you could send yourself the image URLs, and then check those manually.