# How to handle 'ECONNREFUSED' in React with Fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

I have the following code in React that interacts with a third party api. When the Avaya One-X client is not running on the target PC, i get an Error connection refused in the console which is normal. The issue is that the code is set to run every 5 seconds and the console gets filled with these errors whenever the one-x client is not running.

How can i handle this better? Not have it logged so many times would be nice.

```
  fetchData = (url) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then((text) => {
          res(text);
        })
        .catch((e) => rej(e));
    });
  };

  getLogs = async () => {
    try {
      const { user } = this.props.auth;
      const regxmlPromise = this.fetchData(
        `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/registerclient?name=${user.id}`
      );
      const clientIdPromise = this.fetchData(
        `/api/avaya/${user.id}/getclientid/`
      );

      
      const resolves = await Promise.all([regxmlPromise, clientIdPromise]);

      const [registration, clientId] = resolves || [];

      const nextNotification = await this.fetchData(
        `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification?clientid=${clientId}`
      );

      if (registration) {
        const regxml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(registration);
        if (regxml.attributes.ResponseCode === "0") {
          axios.post(`/api/avaya/${user.id}/register/`, regxml);
          console.log("ClientId sent!");
        }
      }

      if (nextNotification) {
        const xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(nextNotification);
        if (
          xml.children[0].name === "VoiceInteractionCreated" ||
          xml.children[0].name === "VoiceInteractionMissed" ||
          xml.children[0].name === "VoiceInteractionTerminated"
        ) {
          console.log(xml);
          console.log(xml.children[0].name);
          axios.post(`/api/avaya/${user.id}/logcalls/`, xml);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  timer = (time) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLogs();
    this.callsInterval = setInterval(this.getLogs, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.callsInterval);
  }
```

To make things more clear, here's a screenshot of the console. I get the Get error with connection refused AND the actual error i catch and log. So even if i catch the error and do nothing with it, i still get that connection refused logged in the console no matter what.

One interesting thing is that if i use fetch-node, i get a different behavior and error message. The error with node is an object and has different props. In React, if i console.log the fetch req error, i only get "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are just trying to hide the network error messages you can click the gear box in Chrome and hit "hide network." Apparently in Chrome, even if you catch network errors they will still bubble up to the console unless you select that. I was using Firefox and did not see the problem at first.

[image]

Some more info can be found here: [Catching net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED for fixing bad img links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512573/catching-neterr-name-not-resolved-for-fixing-bad-img-links)

Answer (score 0):

You can do exponential backoff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff

Basically just increase the time between each fail attempt. Pretty common practice.

If you just don't want to see it you could just catch it but not log it.

Comment: I don't want to increase the number of times between each tries. I just want to stop seeing them in the console. I see them even if i catch and do nothing. Increasing the tries would make the function miss a lot of logs.

Comment: What line is line 24 where the error is thrown? One thing you might be doing wrong is trying to surround everything in a try catch which won't work for async network errors. You would need to do a then catch on `this.getLogs();` but am not sure if that's your issue.

Comment: Line 24 is the fetch(url) request in the fetchData function at the top. Doing a then on this.getLogs();  returns undefined.

Comment: @AdrianSultu submitted another answer, I think you are doing everything correct this seems like a quirk of Chrome.